# font-family override in mac on elementor site

Tags: css, wordpress, macos, font-family, elementor

i have wordpress site thet build with elementor,
and i have problem with the font family in mac it's change to a default font, and it's not let me override this font.

this the website
https://attenmind.co.il

i have tried to do a specific css rules to mac, and its not work

```
html[data-useragent*='Mac OS X'] {
  font-family: inherit;
}

html[data-useragent*='Mac OS X 10_10'] {
  font-family:inherit;
}
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'verdana';
  src: url('https://attenmind.co.il/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/assets/fonts/verdana/Verdana.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('https://attenmind.co.il/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/assets/fonts/verdana/Verdana.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('https://attenmind.co.il/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/assets/fonts/verdana/Verdana.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('https://attenmind.co.il/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/assets/fonts/verdana/Verdana.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('https://attenmind.co.il/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/assets/fonts/verdana/Verdana.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('https://attenmind.co.il/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/assets/fonts/verdana/Verdana.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

html,body{
    font-family: 'verdana', Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
}
```

i just want po prevent mac to ovrride the font family..

thankyou all for the help.

Comment: Please share your css implementation. How you are loading fonts and name the font you are trying to use.

Comment: @Soothran i edit my code now

Comment: remove the quotes in font name. use just verdana instead of 'verdana'

Answer (score 1):

Check if the font you are using is available in the target machine or if it is being loaded externally in your CSS in a supported format (Safari works well with `format('truetype')`, for instance).

If you have the following in CSS:

```css
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

The browser will first use the font "Arial". If the font is not available, it will fallback to the next ("Helvetica") and so on. If none is available, a default font in the browser will be used.

Comment: @yosef-dadya If the answer does not help, try to create a running example in a https://jsbin.com/ or similar service, or point out which font and area in your website is not working properly.

Comment: i edit my cose in the question the verdana font is the problem and i load is proprly in all format and yet it's not working